# Listitem count from cursor Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor

I have a two listview for 1.list show and 2.item show in two different pages, i want to get the number of items in the item page for a specific list and to show the count in the textview. Actually, i got the count of the listview from the cursor but its showing all the item count also from the other list columns.Can anyone help me to find the count for the specific item.Thanks in Advance.

1.db class

```
public void insertContact1(int _id3, int _id4, String content,boolean deleteflag, boolean updateflag, boolean reminder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(Contactsnew.listId, _id3);
    cv.put(Contactsnew.userId1, _id4);
    cv.put("CONTENT", content);
    cv.put(Contactsnew.DELETE_FLAG, deleteflag);
    cv.put(Contactsnew.UPDATE_FLAG, updateflag);
    cv.put(Contactsnew.REMINDER, reminder);

    db = sqlHp.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(Contactsnew.TABLE3, null, cv);
}

public void updateContact1(int _id3, int _id4, String content,boolean deleteflag, boolean updateflag) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();


    cv.put(Contactsnew.listId, _id3);
    cv.put(Contactsnew.userId1, _id4);
    cv.put("CONTENT", content);
    cv.put(Contactsnew.DELETE_FLAG, deleteflag);
    cv.put(Contactsnew.UPDATE_FLAG, updateflag);
    //db.insert(Contactsnew.TABLE03, null, cv);
    db = sqlHp.getWritableDatabase();
    db.update(Contactsnew.TABLE3, cv, Contactsnew.listId + "=" + _id3,null);
    db.close();

}
public static Cursor getcursorvalues(){
    Cursor cur = db.query(Contactsnew.TABLE3, new String[] {Contactsnew.userid,Contactsnew.listId,Contactsnew.CONTENT},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if(cur!=null){
        cur.moveToFirst();
        int str = cur.getCount();
        Log.d("vaal", String.valueOf(str));
    }

    return cur;

}
```

2.mainclass

```
bt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final String category2 = sp.getString("category", null);
                    if(clicked){
                        clicked = false;
                        ArrayList<String> newlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                        TextView curval;
                        for (int i = 0; i < getListView().getCount(); i++) {
                            v = getListView().getChildAt(i);
                            curval = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cursorvalue);
                            curval.setText("    Edit");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        clicked = true;
                        ArrayList<String> newlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                        TextView curval;
                        for (int i = 0; i < getListView().getCount(); i++) {
                            v = getListView().getChildAt(i);
                            curval = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cursorvalue);
                            curval.setText("    0/0");
                            value();
                        }
                    }
        }

        private void value() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Cursor cur = SQLiteConnectornew.getcursorvalues();
             if(cur==null){
                 Log.d("null", "null");
             }
             else{

                 Log.d("returnvalue", "returnvalue");
             }cur.close();
        }
```

Comment: Why dont you just query the columns you want?

Comment: i am new to android, can u givve me a example..

Comment: You are getting clicked position for first list in onItemClick()..right ? Then use that position in query for second list to retrive data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case try these codes

1.sqlite

```
public static Cursor remindervalues(int id, int id1){
     Cursor cur=db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM "+ Contactsnew.TABLE03 + " WHERE " 
              + Contactsnew.listId + " = " + id + " AND " + Contactsnew.userId1 + "=" + id1, 
              null);
    return cur;

}
```

2.in your adapter class

```
Cursor cur = SQLiteConnectornew.remindervalues(id,id1);
    if(cur!=null){
        cur.moveToFirst();
        str = cur.getCount();
        Log.d("vaal", String.valueOf(str));
    }
    String xurva = String.valueOf(str);
    //curval.setText(xurva + "/" + "0");
    cur.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {   

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String retieveValue = lv1.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
                //display value here 

                }
              });
```

Base on retieveValue ,you can get data from database for put data into other listview.

Comment: its retreiving the values, but its showing all the values present in the different items!!thats my question